# To prove the group of homeomorphisms is a metric space

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $(K,d)$ a compact metric space and $Hom(K)$ denotes the set of all homeomorphisms on $K$. Define a map $\rho:Hom(K) \times Hom(K) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by

$$\rho(\phi_1,\phi_2)=sup\{d(\phi_1(x),\phi_2(x)),d(\phi_1^{-1}(x),\phi_2^{-1}(x))\mid x\in K\}.$$

I want to show that $\rho$ is a metric on $Hom(K)$. I have proved all the conditions except the triangle inequality. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: By compactness, the sup is actually a max.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen That is correct, but how it will help in proving the triangle inequality.

Comment: It facilitates the argument because you can consider a specific point $x_0$ such that $\rho(\phi_1,\phi_3)$ is either $d(\phi_1(x_0),\phi_3(x_0))$ or $d(\phi_1^{-1}(x_0),\phi_3^{-1}(x_0))$. Take it from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $\varepsilon>0$, according to the definition of the supremum, there exists $x_0\in K$, such that
$$\rho(\phi_1,\phi_3)\leq d(\phi_1(x_0),\phi_3(x_0))+\varepsilon\quad {\rm or} \quad\rho(\phi_1,\phi_3)\leq d(\phi_1^{-1}(x_0),\phi_3^{-1}(x_0))+\varepsilon.$$
Therefore,
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{aligned}
\rho(\phi_1,\phi_3)&\leq d(\phi_1(x_0),\phi_3(x_0))+\varepsilon\\
   &\leq d(\phi_1(x_0),\phi_2(x_0))+d(\phi_2(x_0),\phi_3(x_0))+\varepsilon\\
   &\leq \rho(\phi_1,\phi_2)+\rho(\phi_2,\phi_3)+\varepsilon.
   \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
or
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{aligned}
\rho(\phi_1,\phi_3)&\leq d(\phi_1^{-1}(x_0),\phi_3^{-1}(x_0))+\varepsilon\\
   &\leq d(\phi_1^{-1}(x_0),\phi_2^{-1}(x_0))+d(\phi_2^{-1}(x_0),\phi_3^{-1}(x_0))+\varepsilon\\
   &\leq \rho(\phi_1,\phi_2)+\rho(\phi_2,\phi_3)+\varepsilon.
   \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
Because of the arbitrariness of $\varepsilon$, we obtain the triangle inequality.

Comment: Indeed, as seen here,  the triangle inequality also holds for non-compact $K$; strictly speaking, compactness is neede “only” to ensure finiteness of $\rho$. Nevertheless, one can make use of compactness for the triangle inequality as well if desired - and get rid of the need to use $\epsilon$.